# type safe Parsing in java

Tags: java, parsing, design-patterns

I am implementing a parser in java.

The data I am parsing has different types of records.
Let's say these are record type A, B, C, ...
These records have some common attributes. so I am thinking of interface Record that all records A, B, C.. will implement.
The data in file will be like:

```
A
B
B
C
C
C
...
X
Y
Z
```

I am thinking to have iterator of records. but it won't be type-safe.
since I can only have

```
interface Record {
   String getRecordName();
   RecordType recordType();
}
class A implements Record {
    @Override
    String getRecordName() {...}
    // record type 'A' specific methods/fields here
}
class B implements Record{
    @Override
    String getRecordName() {...}
    // record type 'B' specific methods/fields..
}
class Parser implements Iterable<Record> {

    boolean hasNext() {...}
     // user has to examine record type and cast
    Record next() { ...} 
}
```

Any way to get around this problem? Could visitor pattern be useful here?

Edit:
Since what I have here is a stream of records (of different types), I would still like composition features. like normal stream has (like map, filter, takeWhile, etc)

Edit :
After thinking through visitor pattern, I think I get another idea. Record interface will have accept(Visitor) method and next() will just return Record(actual type will be concrete record types). Client side will implement a visitor and pass to accept method.

```
interface Record {

  interface Visitor<R> {
      <R> visit(A a);
      <R> visit(B b);
  }
  // add accept method 
  <R> R accept(Visitor<R> v);
}
class A implements Record {
     @Override
     public <R> R accept(Visitor<R> v) {
          return v.visit(this);
     }
}

// client code; r could be A|B
 Record r = parser.next(); 
 String s = r.accept(new Visitor<String>() { ... });
```

Comment: have you tried "instance of" ?

Comment: Yes, visitor pattern is commonly used in parsers.

Comment: "*... it won't be type-safe ...*" could you explain as to why it will not be type-safe?

Comment: Yes visitor pattern is exactly what you need. Don't use `instanceof`.

Comment: @EmreAcar yes i thought of it. but there are many types and I am not sure it is the best way. in FP langugages, pattern matching would be considered as idiomatic.

Comment: Just to be sure that everyone is on the same page - these records also have different functionality? It is necessary to know which record is A, B etc.? Because otherwise you are fine just using the Record interface without casting to the subclasses.

Comment: @kutschkem Yes, different record *types* have different functionality.

Comment: @Nyan Are you planning to have only one `Parser` class? What does the `next` method do? Does it examine the type of record and create the appropriate subclass instance? How does it know what the record type is? Last but not the least, how big a deal is it to have a single domain object called `Record` which has all the possible attributes?

Comment: @CKing  only one parser class. next method will return next record, the record could be any concrete records. (Similar to Variant type in FP languages).

Comment: @Nyan How big a deal would it be to have a single `Record` object that contains all the attributes? This allows both the parser and the client to avoid the need to have any record type checks!

Comment: @CKing It'd be really bad since there are significant difference between different types.

Comment: @Nyan Not quite sure how much value does `String s = r.accept(new Visitor<String>() { ... });` add. I would rather just use casting because 1) Asking the client to call accept method looks nasty to me. 2) You need to add a new `visit` method for each new record type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: it's called the visitor pattern:

```
public interface RecordVisitor {
    void acceptA(A record);
    void acceptB(B record);
    ...
}

public class Parser {
    public void parse(Reader reader, RecordVisitor visitor) {
        ....
    }
}

...
parser.parse(reader, new RecordVisitor() {
    @Override
    void acceptA(A record) {
        ...
    }
    @Override
    void acceptB(B record) {
        ...
    }
    ...
});
...
```

Comment: This does not look scalable. Every time you add a new Record type, one has to modify the interface and the (all) implementation(s). Maybe a mix of Visitor Pattern and Chain of Responsibility would be better fitting.

Comment: @Turing85 re-scalability: this is why such code is often generated (for reasonably evolved DSL) from a grammar definition. For instance, ANTLR will generate very large visitors which would be, indeed, quite cumbersome to write by hand.

Comment: Regarding scalability, will object algebra help? in case there is new record type.

Comment: @Nyan I can't see how. Anyway, if you add more record types, you will want to handle them, so I don't think it's an issue.